# website developed in elementor in default US-en language. But now want to change in espanish

Tags: multisite

I have developed a website using elementor . Default language is US-en. But I want to change the front-end default into Spanish and want my dashboard in english. I changed I went in setting and then in general and changed the language. But it changed the dashboard language, front-end language of home page and others remains in english. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different language in the admin screen by for example changing the Language setting in your user profile.

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/users-your-profile-screen/#your-profile-and-personal-options